# How do I spot syntax error in urls.py file in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am upgrading Django 1.11 to Django 2.2. I did all what have to be done. One tiny problem. It says there is a syntax error in urls.py this is urls.py file here:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page, name='home'),
    path('about/', about_page, name='about'),
    path('accounts/login/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/login')),
    path('accounts/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/account')),
    path('account/', include("accounts.urls"),  # , namespace='account')
    path('accounts/', include("accounts.passwords.urls")),
    path('address/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/addresses')),
    path('addresses/', AddressListView.as_view(), name='addresses'),
    path('addresses/create/', AddressCreateView.as_view(), name='address-create'),
    path('addresses/(?P<pk>\d+)/',
        AddressUpdateView.as_view(), name='address-update'),
    path('analytics/sales/', SalesView.as_view(), name='sales-analytics'),
    path('analytics/sales/data/', SalesAjaxView.as_view(),
        name='sales-analytics-data'),
    path('contact/', contact_page, name='contact'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('checkout/address/create/', checkout_address_create_view,
        name='checkout_address_create'),
    path('checkout/address/reuse/', checkout_address_reuse_view,
        name='checkout_address_reuse'),
    path('register/guest/', GuestRegisterView.as_view(), name='guest_register'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('api/cart/', cart_detail_api_view, name='api-cart'),
    path('cart/', include("carts.urls"),
    path('billing/payment-method/', payment_method_view,
        name='billing-payment-method'),
    path(r'billing/payment-method/create/', payment_method_createview,
        name='billing-payment-method-endpoint'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('bootstrap/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='bootstrap/example.html')),
    path('library/', LibraryView.as_view(), name='library'),
    path('orders/', include("orders.urls"),  # , namespace='orders')
    path('products/', include("products.urls"),  # , namespace='products')
    path('search/', include("search.urls"),  # , namespace='search')
    path('settings/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/account')),
    path('settings/email/', MarketingPreferenceUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='marketing-pref'),
    path('webhooks/mailchimp/', MailchimpWebhookView.as_view(),
        name='webhooks-mailchimp'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

This is the snytax error thrown here. I think I did everything right, still I don't have any clue what is going on wrong here.

```
>   File
> "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eCommerce-master\src\ecommerce\urls.py",
> line 82
>     ]
>     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please kindly help me thank you in advancefor your help

Comment: You don’t need to switch to path when you upgrade, but if you do use path you can’t use regexes - `path('addresses/(?P<pk>\d+)/', ...)` should be `path('addresses/<int:pk>', ...)`.

Comment: oww that as well

Comment: Which ever text editor you're using, usually there are some packages or plugins that highlight the particular matching parantheses/brackets/... or highlight the bug. This could make it easier to find such a bug. Or an IDE like PyCharm will even tell, when parantheses are missing just out of the box without additional packages.

Comment: I am using visualstudio code, can you please recommend one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path('orders/', include("orders.urls"),  # , namespace='orders')
path('products/', include("products.urls"),  # , namespace='products')
path('search/', include("search.urls"),  # , namespace='search')
```

These are missing some parantheses

Comment: lol, embarrassing mistake thank you bro I should have put that in after cuting those namespaces, yeah I will accept this answer in 8 minutes. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me

Comment: @Noor don't mention it. Mark it :)